# java object, приведение типов

Tags: java, объекты

Как в Java Object хранит переменные любого типа? т.е. я могу сказать, что

```
Object ob1 = 1;
Object ob2 = 'x';
```

В одном случае объекту присваиваем целочисленный тип в другом символ и т.д. А как это храниться в объекте? Насколько я знаю `Object` это обычный класс, т.е. у него есть методы, и возможно переменные?  Но что вообще происходит, когда я говорю `ob1 = 1`? Как мы объекту присваиваем примитивный тип? По идее запускается не явное преобразование вроде `ob1 = (Object)1`, но опять же таки что оно делает?

Если мы конвертируем примитивы, то там все понятно. Если мы конвертируем один объект в  другой, тоже понятно. Но как из примитива мы что то конвертируем в объект?

Ну и к слову, что происходит, когда используются `Integer` или `String`? И почему `Object`, который является родителем для Integer и String может содержать и числа и строки, а сами `Integer` и `String` не могут, хотя должны по факту расширять функционал `Object`, а не урезать его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Integer temp = new Integer(1);
Object ob1 = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Автоупаковка**

Это автоматическая инкапсуляция примитивного типа в эквивалентную ему класс-обёртку всякий раз, когда требуется объект данного типа. Это одно из существенных изменений, внесенных в JDK 5.

Autoboxing происходит:

- При присвоении значения примитивного типа переменной соответствующего класса-обёртки.
- При передаче примитивного типа в параметр метода, ожидающего соответствующий ему класс-обёртку.

Читать далее: https://habr.com/ru/post/329498/